# Azure api works locally but not in Azure deployment, for the endpoint which need data from Azure sql db. Endpoint with hardcoded data is fine though

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-api-management

i have deployed a .net core web api to Azure App service. one endpoint of API  which does not have anything to get from Database works fine.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Test data 333"); // Works fine  
                                               // after deployment and get the data  
    }
}
```

**But** the other endpoint of API which has to get data from database ( Azure SQL Database ) **doesnot** **work** and i get error like "apiName.azurewebsites.net/api/controllerName/gtalbsds" is not working as below screenshot. But the same endpoint works fine **locally** with AZURE SQL Database configured in connection string.

appsettings.json

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:<azureServereName>,1433;Initial Catalog=<myDBName>;   
Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<CorrectUserName>;    
Password=<correctPassword>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

C# api code as below

```
[Route("gtalbeds")]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        ItemBasicDetailsList result = new ItemBasicDetailsList();
        using (var context = new myDBContext(this._config))
        {

            var items = context.ItemBasicDetails.ToList();
            if (items != null)
            {
                result = new ItemBasicDetailsList()
                {
                    PackageFee = 150,
                    DeliveryFee = 0,
                    ItemBasicDetails = items
                };
            }
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have an incorrect connection string, but who knows

Comment: its working fine locally with the same connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in Azure , SQL Server linked with your app  if "**Firewall settings" --> Allow Azure services and resources to access this server**" is **Yes**. If it is set to **No**, then change it to **Yes** . This will resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it. Actually in Azure SQL Database instance, "**Firewall settings**" --> **Allow Azure services and resources to access this server** was set to **No**. After setting it to **YES**, the issue was resolved.